# how to find the table integral that contains factorial of n?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, beta-function

I read in this page that" There are lots of definite integrals that depend on a parameter n∈N and whose result contains factorials of n " I am really struggle with this integral
\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t)^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}dt =   \sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{(2j- n)! n!}{(2j+1)!}] 
 \end{align*}\
All what I want where can I find the table integral that contains factorial of n and satisfy the above relation?
I hope at least, anybody can help me to find the table integral that contains factorial of n

Comment: The RHS does not equate to the LHS, unless the "parameter" $n$ in the LHS is actually of no consequence...  Can you give some more details about where you encountered this problem and similar relevant context?

Comment: I think the $n$ on the left side is supposed to be $j$.

Comment: But it's still not true (try e.g. $j=1$).

Comment: Perhaps you mean (if $2j \ge n$)
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}\; dt = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n \choose k} (1+2j-k)^{-1} $$
which can be obtained by substituting $t=s-1$ and binomial expansion.

Comment: Thank you Robert

Comment: Thanks Robert , as you ask me to give more details about this problem, I am trying to prove this problem  \begin{align*}
   \frac{2j+1}{z^{n+1}}  \sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{(2j)!}{(2j- n)! n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t)^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}dt
 \end{align*}\\
 
 
 How can I prove this side  equals \\?
   \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{((2j-n)!n!)}{(2j!)}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n z^{-n-1}  
  \end{align*}